# How do I count the number of nonzero pixel using frames in live camera? It works with image but it doesn't in frames. I'm using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, cvzone

```
import cv2
import pickle
import cvzone
import numpy as np

#video feed
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


with open("CarParkPos", "rb") as f:
    posList = pickle.load(f)

width, height = 100, 50

def checkParkingSpace(frameProcess):
    for pos in posList:
        x,y = pos

        frameCrop = frame[y:y+height, x:x+width]
        cv2.imshow(str(x*y), frameCrop)
        count = cv2.countNonZero(frameCrop)
        cvzone.putTextRect(frame, "asd", (x,y+height-3), scale = 1, thickness=2, offset=0)
```

cv2.countNonZero doesn't seem to work when counting pixels in a live camera, but it works fine when using a video file.

```
#converted rgb camera to black and white
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frameGray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    frameBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(frameGray, (3,3), 1)
    frameThreshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(frameBlur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                                           cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 25, 16)
    frameMedian = cv2.medianBlur(frameThreshold,5)
    kernel = np.ones((1,1), np.uint8)
    frameDilate = cv2.dilate(frameMedian,kernel, iterations = 1)

    checkParkingSpace(frameDilate)
    
    #writing the rectangle shapes in camera
    for pos in posList:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, pos, (pos[0] + width, pos[1] + height), (0, 200, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I don't fully understand all the codes since I just watched a tutorial. What I'm trying to do is exactly the one in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=caKnQlCMIYI , but instead  of using video file I want to use a live camera.

Comment: why do you think any of those pixels would be zero? show the pictures/frames you use. and perhaps present a [mre]. your first piece of code never calls that function so it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
for pos in posList:
    x,y = pos

    frameCrop = frame[y:y+height, x:x+width]
    cv2.imshow(str(x*y), frameCrop)
    count = cv2.countNonZero(cv2.Canny(frameCrop, 100, 200))
    cvzone.putTextRect(frame, str(count), (x,y+height-3), scale = 1, thickness=2, offset=0)
```

What I did was canny the frame then count the non-black pixel.